# How to show ActionStatus spinner without using the reRender tag on button

Tags: visualforce, controller, rerender, actionstatus

I am using an SLDS VF page, where I display search parameters. When "Search" button is clicked, the parameters are picked up and a call is made to an external resource, and if there are any matches they are returned to the VF page. My goal is to display a spinner until results are returned. I am able to display the spinner only if I add reRender tag on my button. Unfortunately my page breaks when I do that, meaning my spinner spins and no results are displayed. Are there any workarounds?

```
    <apex:outputPanel id="searchPanel">
        <li class="slds-button-group-item">
           <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" value="Search" action="{!doAdvSearch}" status = "recordSearchid" reRender= "cdireturn"/>
              <apex:actionStatus id="recordSearchid">
                <apex:facet name="start">
                  <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:4rem">
                   <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_inline">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                       <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                       <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </apex:facet>
              </apex:actionStatus>
        </li>
    </apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="cdireturn">    
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showAdvSearchResults}">
                       <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                       <div class="slds-truncate "></div>
                       </th>

                       <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                       <div class="slds-truncate "></div>
                       </th>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: You MUST use reRender to get the spinner with commandButton. You'll want to approach this from the other direction: why is your page breaking when you use reRender...?

Comment: This does make a lot of sense. My VF page essentially has 2 output panels. The first one contains fields that a user populates. When a button "Search" is clicked, I perform an API call. When results come back I display them in my second output panel. If I do not have the reRender tag on the button, my results set/ouputPanel is displayed. when the reRender is used, the spinner keeps on spinning. I am referencing in the reRender tag the id of my secondary/result output pannel. Happy to put my code in here but it is a lot.

Comment: I updated the code. In this case the spinner does not stop spinning and my cdireturn outputpannel does not display. In my logs I can see that the data comes back, but the pannel is not displaying.

Comment: Is the `outputPanel` having the complete code? I cannot see any result being displayed in the code currently. Also, as you are using rendered attribute in the `outputPanel`. You would need to create a parent `outputPanel` component and rerender that. For ex: `<apex:outputPanel id="cdireturn"><apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showAdvSearchResults}" >...</apex:outputPanel></apex:outputPanel>`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I updated as you requested, but the spinner keeps running, and the outputpanel is still not rendured. I am at a loss.

Comment: I figured that my problem is around rerender tag on my second panel. It loads or evaluates the criteria of if the panel instantly, and in my case on my controller certain logic has to execute and return the information which is happening after the layout is already rendered. Not sure how I can solve for this either.